# How can I create view controller that is defined in XIB?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, ios7

Sorry for perhaps noob question, guys. I'm new to iOS development.

How can I create view controller that is defined in XIB ?

When you create new class inherited from `UIViewController` in Xcode via "New File" and mark `with XIB` checkbox it creates xib file that doesn't have `viewController` element. But rather it has `placeholder` which points to `UIViewController` which is defined **in the code**.

But I see that you can create controller itself in Interface Builder and specify customClass for it.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I get `loaded the "EmbeddedViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set` error in run-time. But I believed `view` property must be set by resource loader automatically since everything is defined via XIB. It works that way for TableView and its cells for example.

Could you please provide example how to do it ?

I created sample project: https://github.com/cppexpert/SampleWithNib

The controller in question is *[EmbeddedViewController](https://github.com/cppexpert/SampleWithNib/blob/ba453c7492f24ef715832ce780c5b16f2e8a4698/Sample43/EmbeddedViewController.xib)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out these controls exist in IB for Storyboard projects.

Comment: This is the real answer. You arrived at the correct conclusion and other people were just misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 9):

Create one Xib per UIViewController

Each Xib have File's Owner object for you to set UIViewController class there. Click File's Owner and choose EmbeddedViewController on it's class

Then drag main UIView not UIViewController class to there, then hook up this view with file's owner as view. UIViewController just use to drag to StoryBoard base project.

https://github.com/lequysang/gitfiles02/blob/master/SampleWithNib-master.zip

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of `viewController` element in `EmbeddedViewController.xib` in your version of the file ?

Comment: I forgot to delete. Just delete it

Answer (score 2):

When you create a view controller with xib via "new file", Xcode generates an `UIView` and connects it with `view` outlet automatically. Seems like you changed something after Xcode generated the xib file. In that case you need to connect a view to the `view` outlet manually.

Comment: Yep, that works. That would be standard XIB Xcode generates. But I was wondering how I can do it without using File's Owner and just use `viewController` element in XIB ?

Comment: You don't need a `viewController` element. In most cases file's owner is the view controller.

Comment: If it's not needed why I can create `viewController` in Interface Builder then ? :)

Comment: You can add view controller objects and specify custom classes like you said. But the added view controller's `view` outlet is not connected to a view automatically. So you need to add a view to the controller and connect it to the outlet manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new view in xib.set the file owner to your custom class.
Or if you simply want to create a view.
Then

```
NSArray* test1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];
self.myViewFromNib = [test1 objectAtIndex:0];
```

Where myViewFromNib is your view object and "View" is your nib name.

Comment: The question was about view controller, not about view.